# Converting Unix timestamp to timestamp including the local time of a certain timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have following code:

```
df['time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['unix_time'], unit='s'))
df['time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['unix_time'], unit='s',tz='Europe/Vienna'))
```

First line runs but when I try to set the new timestamp as a local time for that timezone I get an error as - `**`**to_datetime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tz'**`**`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.to_datetime(df['unix_time'], unit='s').tz_localize('Europe/Vienna')
```

or alternatively

```
pd.to_datetime(df['unix_time'], unit='s',utc=True).tz_convert('Europe/Vienna')
```

Comment: I get an error of index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex when I try above